# In-app purchase incorrectly charged twice

Tags: java, android, google-play, in-app-purchase

I just tested my first in-app purchase and the amount went of twice of the amount that should have.

I used [this](https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3) library to implement in-app billing into my application. Here is how I implemented it:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BillingProcessor.IBillingHandler {

private Button buyButton;
BillingProcessor bp;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    bp = new BillingProcessor(this, "myKeyGoesHere", this);

    buyButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buyButton);

    buyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                bp.purchase(MainActivity.this, "mypurchasekey");

            }
        }
    });


}


@Override
public void onProductPurchased(@NonNull String productId, @Nullable TransactionDetails details) {

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successfully Purchased",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

@Override
public void onPurchaseHistoryRestored() {

}

@Override
public void onBillingError(int errorCode, @Nullable Throwable error) {

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Billing Error",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

@Override
public void onBillingInitialized() {

}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (!bp.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (bp != null) {
        bp.release();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

}
```

The popup that comes up before buying, displays the correct amount and I have included tax into the amount. The amount was/displays as 3.99 and 8.00 went off my bank account?

I tried finding more information about this, but could not find any.

Comment: Why would you use a third party billing library now that Google have released an official one? https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library.html

Comment: take a look at the thread - https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3/issues/60.. if its not similar upload logs in your question to take a look

Comment: @Kuffs can you please give me a example of how to implement that library, except the TrivialDrive example which is very confusing.

Comment: No sorry because it depends on what parts of the library you want to use.  Full instructions are here: https://developer.android.com/training/play-billing-library/index.html